# How do I update the input value using an onchange event and get the value in vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am doing an assignment where I make a simple API call using fetch to retrieve an image a of dog by breed. The one issue I can't resolve is that the input value never changes when I try to retrieve an image of a different breed. the default value, which is 'hound', reappears after I press submit. I know I need to attach an `onchange` event to my input but I am not sure how to write it or how to get the value after the `onchange` event is triggered. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I originally wrote this with jQuery but decided to rewrite it in vanilla JavaScript so that's why there is no jQuery.
I put a '<---' on the line I am struggling with.

P.S I know my code isn't very good, I am new to this.

JavaScript

```
function getJson(breed) {
  fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breed/" + breed + "/images/random")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => displayResults(responseJson));
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  const dogImage = responseJson.message;
  let breedImage = "";
  let container = document.createElement("div");
  console.log(dogImage);
  breedImage += `<img src="${dogImage}">`;
  container.innerHTML = breedImage;
  document.querySelector(".results-img").innerHTML = "";
  document.querySelector(".results-img").appendChild(container);
}

function submitButton() {
  let breedName = document.querySelector("#numberValue").value;
  breedName.addEventListener().onchange.value; <---
  document.getElementById("dog-input").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    getJson(breedName);
  });
}

submitButton();
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Dog Api</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <input id="numberValue" type="text" value="hound" />
        <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <section class="results">
        <h2>Look at these Dogs!</h2>
        <div class="results-img"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an `onchange` event handler. Currently you're storing the value of the input in `breedName` when you call `submitButton`. That means that `breedName` will never change because it is merely a reference to the value at that moment.

Instead create a reference to the element and read the `value` property in the submit event handler. That will get the value how it is at the time you submit.

```js
function getJson(breedName) {
  console.log(breedName);
}

function submitButton() {
  const form = document.querySelector('#dog-form');
  const input = document.querySelector('#numberValue');
  form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const breedName = input.value;
    getJson(breedName);
  });
}

submitButton()
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Dog Api</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form id="dog-form">
        <input id="numberValue" type="text" value="hound" />
        <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <section class="results">
        <h2>Look at these Dogs!</h2>
        <div class="results-img"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! I changed the function but it doesn't display anything. Should I keep the submit event listener or are you saying to scrap it all together?

Comment: The submit event listener was listening for the event on the `#dog-input` element, but I couldn't see it in your example so it wouldn't be doing anything.  If the `submitButton` function is called, then the event listener should be working. Is your console giving you any errors?

Comment: No errors, it simply doesn't display any images. I really appreciate your input though!

Comment: And if you use `console.log(breedName)` inside the change event handler after  the `const breedName = ...` line, what does it say? And is your `submitButton` being called?

Comment: I put a console.log and nothing appears, something must be wrong with the event listener. The function `submitButton` is being called at the bottom.

Comment: The event listener should work. Do note that `change` only fires when the focus leaves the input element. Try switching over to `input` to fire the event handler whenever the value is immediately changed. I've added an example.

Comment: It isn't working, I tried adding `event.preventDefault()` and it didn't seem to change anything. The page just reloads and nothing happens. I am really sorry because I feel like I'm wasting your time. If you have any other ideas I can try them out but if you don't want to keep trying that's okay too!

Comment: Haha, well I just figured out that I'm giving you a solution that won't fix your issue. I've update the answer. Do note that the HTML has also been changed slightly to select the `<form>` element.

Comment: Oh my god... you GOT IT TO WORK!!!! You are a genius and an icon! THANK YOU!